# TCPClient closes when resizing control

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, user-controls, tcpclient

In a C# Winforms project I have a UserControl class that has a TcpClient as a private member.
The TcpClient is set to null when the user drags or otherwise resizes the UserControl's parent class. The TcpClient is not set to null when the the UserControl's parent starts maximized or minimized. The code that deals with the TcpClient runs in a seperate thead. I haven't been able to find any other users with this problem.

I've tried setting breakpoints on the UserControl's constructor and destructor, to no avail. The code looks like this:

```
public partial class IPCInterface: UserControl
{
    private TcpClient aClient = null;
    private bool IsRunning = true;
    private Thread ShellThread = null;
    // [SNIP]
    private void MainLoop()
    {
        // The exception occurs in this function when resizing
        try
        { 
            // The exception is thrown here, aClient.Client.Get returns null -> nullreference exception
            while (IsRunning && aClient.Client.Connected == true)
            {
                while (aClient.Client.Available > 0)
                    ShellInputOutputBox.Invoke(
                        (MethodInvoker)delegate () 
                        {
                            ShellInputOutputBox.Text += ReceiveString();
                        });

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            if(aClient.Client.Connected == true)
                aClient.Client.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);  // The exception occurs here when resizing
        }

    }

    public IPCInterface(TcpClient IPCStream)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        aClient = IPCStream;
        ShellThread = new Thread(() => MainLoop());
        ShellThread.Start();
    }
```

I'm at wits end as to why this is happening. Does anybody know how I can counteract the closing of the socket?

Additional information:

The UserControl itself is located inside a tab interface which is also located in a tab interface (I'm not a UX designer...). All these interfaces are anchored to the outer edges of their parents so that they move when the user resizes the main form.

Comment: In your code I see a comment `// The exception occurs in this function when resizing` If you have located an exception better post the exception info.

Comment: Done, the exception throws in the coditional statement for the while loop. The aClient.Client variable is set to null.

Comment: I don't think it has anything related to resizing. Is something null? What happens when you debug?

Comment: Sounds like some sort of general structural problem with your app.  Could be any number of things interacting with the UI from other places in your code...

Comment: @AkshayMahajan None of the other threads are doing anything interesting when the application breaks. No other function is called that touches the TcpClient. The destructor is not called, neither is the constructor. I do see that the layout of my application changes a moment before the exception is thrown, which is what leads me to believe it has something to do with resizing the application.

Comment: Does the control has default constructor if so it is not shown on the code and maybe your default constructor is not initializing the TCPClient?

Comment: @DannyD The TCPClient is initialized. The application works fine until I resize the application. At which point the TCPClient is set to null.

Comment: Best practice : if you are not planing to change the value of member field (tcpClient) outside the constructor declare it as readonly . this prevents accidental re-initialization of the fields ( which i think is whats happening here )

Comment: @DannyD Sadly this does not appear to have helped. I'm starting to suspect a bug in the implementation of winforms itself, or some esoteric problem with garbage collection and object ownership. This bug only happens when I drag the form, and no where else in the code do I touch the TcpClient. Exactly the same problem occurs when I remove the client as a member from the UserControl and instead pass it as a parameter to the mainloop function by using ParameterizedThreadStart().

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. It turned out to be an object ownership problem combined with the fact that winforms apparently triggers a garbage collection when resizing the form.

Somewhere else in the code I create the connection that's used by the UserControl like this:

```
        public static TcpClient OpenSession(string ServerIp, int ServerPort)
        {
            cServerControl Result = new cServerControl(ServerIp, ServerPort);
            Result.Connect();

            // [SNIP]

            return Result.TcpClient;
        }
```

I think C# concludes that since the cServerControl is created in a thread that's separate from the thread that will later interact with the TcpClient, it can safely dispose of the TcpClient. Ignoring the fact that the TcpClient is explicitly transferred to the new thread. Changing the code to return the cServerControl (and using the cServerControl in the UserControl instead of the TcpClient) fixes the issue, as the cServerControl is now not marked for disposal.